# AngularJS ui-router: access child scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have such routes:

```
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('articles', {
    url: '/articles',
    views: {
      main: {
        controller: 'ArticlesCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('articles.edit', {
    url: '/upd/:itemId',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.edit.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesEditCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
  .state('articles.add', {
    url: '/add/news/',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.add.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesAddCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
})
```

and i'm updating some data in `articles` state, how can i force child controller with state `articles.edit` to update it's `$scope.someVar` with data from first state controller, without using services? Which way of solving this issue it the best one?

Comment: you need `$broadcast` check http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html

Comment: Sounds like you need to organize routes so you will have 'articles' as parent route(abstract) and sub routes like `edit` and `add`. I this case you will be able to place common logic in "abstract" controller.

Comment: @singhakash it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since controller functions are 'newed' objects you could use the prototype of controllers to pass data around through an object like this

```js
var obj = {}
function ArticlesCtrl($scope){
  obj.ArticlesCtrl = ArticlesCtrl.prototype

  ArticlesCtrl.prototype.passData = function(data){
    //...do stuff with data passed from ArticlesEditCtrl
  }
  
}

function ArticlesEditCtrl(){
  obj.ArticlesCtrl.passData('some data here')
}

.config(function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('articles', {
    url: '/articles',
    views: {
      main: {
        controller: 'ArticlesCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('articles.edit', {
    url: '/upd/:itemId',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.edit.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesEditCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
  .state('articles.add', {
    url: '/add/news/',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.add.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesAddCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

put your function resolve just like that

```
$stateProvider.state('articles', {
url: '/articles',
views: {
  main: {
    controller: 'ArticlesCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'actions/articles/articles.html'
  }resolve: {
                time: function AnyFunction(SessionTimer)
                {
                    SessionTimer.startTimer();
                }
            }
```

Comment: could you provide an example with variables?